# Handling duplicate items for Twitter feed?

Tags: android, twitter

I'm trying now to create Twitter app &  implemented to list the 20 recent tweets of Home Timeline in a `listview`.

When refreshing after a minute, it adds the new 5 tweets + the old processed previous 15 tweets. (**Duplication** arises here).

So, how should i prevent adding already duplicate tweets again and again when refreshing?

Answer (score 1):

Check if each new tweet is already in the adapter after you download it.  Easiest way to do that is to use a HashMap.  When you get a tweet, check the map.  If the tweet is in there, skip it.  If it isn't, add it to the map and the list.

Comment: so, should i use tweet_id as a primary here right to check whether the tweet was already present or not?

Comment: Yes. Use that as the key to the map.  The value doesn't matter-  in fact you can use a HashSet instead of HashMap because there is no real value for a bit of a performance improvement.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the help.

Comment: Hi, can u tell how to do with Hashset?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the `since_id` parameter of the [Home Timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline).

For example, if the most recent tweet had an id of "123456789", you would call `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?since_id=123456789` - that way Twitter will only give you the tweets which occurred *after* your last refresh.

Comment: It does. You need to use paging.  See http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Paging.html

Comment: It mentioned there. But, when i try only `max_id` , `since_id` along with `max_id` works. But, not alone with `since_id`.